# Vue.js / Vuetify 3 router working incorrectly

Tags: vue.js, web, vuetify.js

I'm currently building a website via vue.js with the vuetify 3 framework. I have following problem with my vue.js router:

My website works completely fine, I can click on links on my main page whom take me to subpages. However if I don't call my main page (here I'll call it example.shop) "example.shop" but something like example.shop/contact via the address bar in my browser, it gives me a 404 not found error. I can however easily access the contact page via a link on the main page.

I'll state the content of my index.js which the router uses beneath.

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    component: () => import("@/layouts/default/Default.vue"),
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        name: "Home",
        component: () =>
          import(/* webpackChunkName: "home" */ "@/views/Home.vue"),
      },
      {
        path: "/contact",
        name: "Contact",
        component: () =>
          import(/* webpackChunkName: "home" */ "@/views/Contact.vue"),
      },
      {
        path: "/tos",
        name: "Terms of Service",
        component: () =>
          import(/* webpackChunkName: "home" */ "@/views/TOS.vue"),
      },
      {
        path: "/imprint",
        name: "Imprint",
        component: () =>
          import(/* webpackChunkName: "home" */ "@/views/Imprint.vue"),
      },
      {
        path: "/shop",
        name: "Shop",
        component: () =>
          import(/* webpackChunkName: "home" */ "@/views/Shop.vue"),
      },
    ],
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: The webserver should be configured for SPA, i.e. respond with index.html for any 404. Currently it isn't.